# How to check Balance & send ERC721 Tokens

Tags: transactions, balances, erc-721

I have [SPH ERC721 Tokens](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0b9D7d0c6C1968EDd3E84ABf6499Bc9Cf96F2575#tokentxnsErc721).

How can I check balance like ERC20 and send ERC721 tokens token to Exchange or in other wallet ?

Answer (score 0):

## The easy way

Find the token address, it is

[image]

[image]

It is:

> 0x7B00aE36C7485B678Fe945c2DD9349Eb5Baf7b6B

And paste that into MyEtherWallet.

[image]

If you want to actually access the full capabilities of this contract you need the ABI. ZeppelinOS messes that up pretty good because it adds mutability "features". See ["THE HARD WAY" answer here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64889/26015). And you can paste that ABI in.

To save a lot of time you can assume that the SPACE ERC-721 token is similar to Su Squares, another ERC-721 token. So select Su Squares from the drop down box and then paste in the address 0x7B00aE36C7485B678Fe945c2DD9349Eb5Baf7b6B and you are good to go.

You can now access your balance, token ownership and transfer tokens. You can ignore the `personalize` and some other functions that are specific to Su Squares, they won't work, they will just throw if you try.

Answer (score -1):

## Hard core answer

***This is a literal answer to inspect how the contract actually works. Simpler answer also coming.***

In general you will click here to see details:

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, this contract unfortunately uses Zeppelin OS which makes reading and using the contract much more difficult. In addition, it removes all the immutability guarantees of using blockchain in the first place.

---

Etherscan has a problem with this contract (`implementation` is inaccurately shown as `0x0`) so we can access it another way. On Etherscan, access the Code tab and EXPORT ABI at the bottom. Choose the RAW export. For convenience I have pasted it here:

> [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newImplementation","type":"address"}],"name":"upgradeTo","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newImplementation","type":"address"},{"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"upgradeToAndCall","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"implementation","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"changeAdmin","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"admin","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_implementation","type":"address"},{"name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"previousAdmin","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"AdminChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"implementation","type":"address"}],"name":"Upgraded","type":"event"}]

Before you leave the page, also collect the token contract address

> 0x7B00aE36C7485B678Fe945c2DD9349Eb5Baf7b6B

--

Visit https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts and access the contracts page.

WARNING: EVERY TIME YOU CLICK A LINK TO MY ETHER WALLET YOU NEED TO TRIPLE CHECK THAT YOU ARE NOT ACCESSING A PHISHING LINK!

^ But in this case you don't actually need to be logged in and you can use Private Browsing mode.

Enter the contract address and the ABI. Then use the drop down to get the implementation address...

[image]

All of these above approaches failed due to bugs with the tools.

Instead I used this hard core way to find the actual implementation: pick a recent transaction, find the delegate call, and find where the call is delegating to.

[image]

There it is --- right now the contract is delegating to

> 0x0bA64224c056532a880BDcC8Ab035715BCF70a0b

And I needed to add a leading zero to make that work.

Of course for a computer that is currently valued at $14B, it should not be so difficult to use.

Now that you know the backing implementation, you can see how it works normally.